# Why can't Google index my site?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, sitemap

I want Google to index a number of pages on my website, but when I request Google to index the site, it raises an error. How come?

Am I doing anything wrong somewhere?

The error it's throwing is a soft 404, but if you go to my homepage, everything is fine, and nothing seems to be wrong.

[image]

Someone please help! This is my first time working with search engine web crawlers.

## Edit #1

The same thing is happening for Bing as well, so I must be doing *something* wrong.

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you figured out the issue, but we generally don't [troubleshoot individual sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that we have to visit because they can change, so questions here are required to be self-contained so that they'll be helpful to others in the future (we remove URLs for that reason as well).

Comment: @dan Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Sure - sorry to have to close it. Be sure to accept your answer when you get a chance though (for the extra rep), and feel free to ask other questions here in the future.

Comment: @dan No problem - appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was because I had a button that linked to a '404 Error page game' that I had made, and Google chose to interpret that as a Soft 404, which is pretty annoying.

If the page contains terms like `404`, `not found`, etc, Google seems to flag that as a Soft 404 (which kinda makes sense, but is a bit annoying)

I still have the issue with Bing, but they take a lot longer to process and index sites than Google does, so I'll leave an update here if that changes (I'm not too worried if Bing can't detect it because their top search term is 'Google')